# Loop over a variable prefix in SPSS for regression

Tags: regression, spss

I want to loop over a variable index to generate a regression model for each predictor. This is not possible with either loop or do repeat.

I have a set of predictors like var1_indep, var2_indep, var3_indep.and I would like to produce three regressions; one for each of the predictors.

```
loop # = 1 to 2.
regress /dependent my_dep_var /method=enter var_#_indep.
end loop.
```

However, the loop command is not valid for regression. Anyone knows if there is an alternative? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As the correct answer goes, you should use macro facility or (another option) python programmability. Loop command operates only on transformations of data cases, it cannot do cycling of procedures.

Comment: To loop over prefixes in a macro, use !concat function within !do !v !in() cycle

Answer (score 1):

You can use a macro for this. See [DEFINE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_24.0.0/spss/base/syn_define_overview.html) in the documentation.

```
define regs()
    !do !i=1 !to 3.
        reg /dep my_dep_var /enter !concat('var_',!i,'_indep').
    !doend
!enddefine.

regs
```